# VERY simple C program won't compile with VC 64

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction

Here is a very simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("sizeof(short) = %d\n",(int)sizeof(short));
    printf("sizeof(int) = %d\n",(int)sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(long) = %d\n",(int)sizeof(long));
    printf("sizeof(long long) = %d\n",(int)sizeof(long long));
    printf("sizeof(float) = %d\n",(int)sizeof(float));
    printf("sizeof(double) = %d\n",(int)sizeof(double));

    return 0;
}
```

While it compiles fine on Win32 (command line: `cl main.c`), it does not using the Win64 compiler (`"c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe" main.c`). Specifically, it sais "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol printf referenced in function main". As far as I understand this, it can not link to `printf`, right?

Obviously, I have Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 2008 (Standard enu) x86 and x64 installed and am using the 64-bit flavor of Windows (7).

What is the problem here?

**UPDATE:**
OK, now I ran `vcvarsall.bat amd64`. It sais "The specified configuration type is missing. The tools for this configuration might not be installed.". As mentioned, the compiler clearly is installed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at vcvarsall.bat it will print the specified configuration missing statement if certain batch files are missing.

For the amd64 option this file must exist:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat
```

Comment: it's not there. Do you have an idea what is wrong with my installation? (I did not manipulate it or something)

Comment: Is just the file missing or the whole directory? The "bin\amd64" directory is the 64-bit compiler (cl.exe is a 64-bit application). The bin\x86_amd64 is the 64-bit cross compiler (cl.exe is a 32-bit application). Maybe you only have the 32-bit version of the 64-bit compiler installed? If you try "vcvarsdll x86_amd64" does it work?

Comment: just the one file. I guess I am missing the SP1, which is currently downloading.

Comment: If bin\x86_amd64 is there, then why don't you use the cross compiler?

Comment: If you don't have SP1 that would be a good first step. Otherwise - you could go to Add/Remove programs and do a Repair on Visual Studio 2008 to see if the file appears (or reappears).

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with your setup. It compiles & link fine for me.

> D:>cl test.cpp Microsoft (R) C/C++
>   Optimizing Compiler Version
>   15.00.30729.01 for x64 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> test.cpp Microsoft (R) Incremental
>   Linker Version 9.00.30729.01 Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> /out:test.exe test.obj
>
> D:>

Did you run vcvarsall.bat with the right options to set up the environment variables before you try running cl.exe? Something along the line of

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a 32bit or 64bit system? I'm guessing from the path that the 64bit standard libraries aren't available, at least not in that directory.